# Is it a good idea to use a const pointer to FILE type?

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, c-standard-library, const-pointer

Normally, C file I/O is done using `FILE*` as this is what the standard library functions all take.

In C, one can also have a *const pointer*, where the address of the pointer cannot change (but the value it points to can be).

I wondered if this could be applied to `FILE*`, so wrote this small program to test this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    FILE* const file = fopen("somefile.txt", "w");
    if (file != NULL) {
        fprintf(file, "%s\n", "So this works? That's just swell!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine and works as intended on Ubuntu/Linux 16.04 using GCC (the file contains exactly the string I expected), but I'm not sure if this idiom is such a good idea —the `FILE` type is opaque by design and handling of it is implementation-specific.

Because there's no guarantee that any C library implementation won't try and change the address of the `FILE` pointer, is it safer to not use this approach when doing I/O in C?

Comment: This simply means that you can't change the value of `file`.  It's entirely up to you whether that's useful.

Comment: You've told the compiler that *your* code won't change the value of `file`. This has no effect on the standard library functions. Note that `FILE* const file` is different from `const FILE* file`. The latter says that what `FILE*` points to is `const`. In that case, you should get warnings from the compiler when you attempt to pass `file` to the standard library functions.

Comment: You can use `FILE * const` sanely; you cannot use `const FILE *` sanely.  There's a guarantee that none of the functions in the C library will modify the pointer part of the `FILE *` you pass to them in any way detectable by the calling code, because the pointer is always passed by value — never the address of the pointer.  So there is *no way* for the calling code to modify your pointer — unless it goes to insanely complex steps in order to do so, and it won't because there is neither any need nor any benefit to doing so,.

Comment: I'm aware of the difference between `FILE * const` and `const FILE *` (as well as why the latter doesn't make any sense). In my question I am seeking to clarify whether making the pointer `const` will have any negative impact on the standard library functions, as they don't take const pointers in their prototypes.

Comment: Also, for context of why I'm looking to do this —the same reasons why one might make any other pointer _const_: to stop an accidental re-assignment of what it points to!

Comment: It can't have any effect on the functions in the library; they are passed a copy of the value, and they won't modify the value, but won't be aware that the value is non-modifiable anyway, and won't care.  Using `FILE * const fp = fopen(...);` simply means you can't reuse that file pointer for anything else in the same function, and you can't reset it to NULL after you `fclose()` it.  Otherwise, it has no effect.  I don't think it's useful; it isn't harmful except that it does nothing beneficial.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler aha! I didn't realise const pointers worked in that way when passed into functions. It looks like what you've written should maybe be the answer.

Comment: Standard functions that take `int` or `size_t` don't usually take a `const` but you can pass them the constant `0` no problem. Think why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer as requested.*</sup>

You can use `FILE * const` sanely; you cannot use `const FILE *` sanely. There's a guarantee that none of the functions in the C library will modify the pointer part of the `FILE *` you pass to them in any way detectable by the calling code, because the pointer is always passed by value — never the address of the pointer. So there is no way for the calling code to modify your pointer — unless it goes to insanely complex steps in order to do so, and it won't because there is neither any need nor any benefit to doing so.

> I'm aware of the difference between `FILE * const` and `const FILE *` (as well as why the latter doesn't make any sense). In my question I am seeking to clarify whether making the pointer const will have any negative impact on the standard library functions, as they don't take const pointers in their prototypes.
>
> Also, for context of why I'm looking to do this — the same reasons why one might make any other pointer const: to stop an accidental re-assignment of what it points to.

It can't have any effect on the functions in the library; they are passed a copy of the value, and they won't modify the value, but won't be aware that the original value is non-modifiable anyway, and won't care. Using `FILE * const fp = fopen(…);` simply means you can't reuse that file pointer for anything else in the same function (or retry opening a different file name or calling a different 'open' function), and you can't reset it to NULL after you `fclose()` it.  Of course, if the pointer goes out of scope because it is inside a loop, it can be reused when the scope is re-entered.

Otherwise, using `FILE * const` has no effect. I don't think it's useful. It isn't harmful except that it does nothing beneficial (and might confuse people).  I recommend against using `FILE * const`.

Comment: One huzzah for the last paragraph.

Comment: Yes, thanks —that last bit is especially helpful. I think I will follow your recommendation, it makes the most sense.

Comment: Wouldn't using `FILE *const` give the compiler hints that may help it optimize a function?

Comment: @SOStinks: Can you think of an optimization that would be available with the `const` qualifier that wouldn't be available without it?  If you work alone, never distribute your code for others to look at, and you want to use it, be my guest, but take pity on your co-workers and people who are reading your code — don't use `FILE * const`; IMO, it confuses people without conveying any benefit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not a compiler writer so I cannot give you a technical answer but presumably some of the same optimizations that are achievable for other const pointers and values would also apply to a const FILE pointer. As for coworkers, I don't see your point of view. I they know C they know what const means and so I don't see why think it'd be so terrible. If anything, I see it as helping them understand code. Whenver I see "const", it tremendously helps me understand the following code as my brain locks onto the fact that this value won't change, which makes parsing code far easier.